# Restrict Android Studio from installing in Work Profile

Tags: android, android-studio

When I press the Run button inside Android Studio and select my device, it installs the app on both my user as well as the work profile. Is there any setting inside Android Studio which can help me prevent installing the app inside the Work user, as my organization can track each and every thing happening on the work profile.